# '#$A' characters messing up my Regex

Tags: regex, delphi, indy

I have standard procedure to download data from the web using Indy idHTTP

```
sAdv := GetHTTP.Get(inURL);  //sAdv is a String type.
// next send sAdv to a Regex processor
```

I'm using the following regex to extract data from `sAdv`

```
(R\d{3})\s(\d{3})\s\w{2}\sQD\s(\d{3})\s\w{2}\sQD\s(\d{3})\s\w{2}\sQD\s(\d{3})\s\w{2}\sQD
```

Here's an example of how the data looks on the web.

```
T000 205N 1327E 085 R064 035 NE QD 035 SE QD 035 SW QD 035 NW QD R050 065 NE QD 065 SE QD 055 SW QD 055 NW QD R034 120 NE QD 140 SE QD 145 SW QD 135 NW QD
```

This has been working flawlessly until recently.
I looked at the contents of the `aAdv` which now contain some additional characters that are not visible when viewing it on the website.
There are random `'#$A'` throughout the line which messes up the regex match.

```
T000 205N 1327E 085 R064 035 NE QD 035 SE QD 035 SW QD 035 NW Q'#$A'D R050 065 NE QD 065 SE QD 055 SW QD 055 NW Q'#$A'D R034 120 NE QD 140 SE QD 145 SW QD 135 NW QD
```

I'm guessing these are hidden when viewed on the website, but when downloaded into a string variable in my GetHTTP.Get(inURL) above they show up.

Any suggestions on how I resolve this problem?

Comment: These are linefeeds. Strip them if you don't want them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Thanks again for your help.  I'll use StringReplace to strip them out.